# How to open default date picker by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webview

In normal html, I use below code to define an input date picker which allow user to select date in a popup calendar. It works fine.

```
<input type='date'></input>
```

but now, I want to show the date picker on a onClick function of a button. I know that there may be some other 3rd party date picker component available. But I don't want to bring new dependencies in my application. So i am looking for a default way to support this behavior.

BTW, my web app is built on react, redux framework. And it is running on android and iOS webview. If the default date picker doesn't support this requirement, any 3rd party component which is fit for mobile device and compatible with react is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Give id to the input tag and then on click of a button use .focus() event

For eg: onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input').focus()"